# Import functions in python Add-In logic script

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-addin

I am running into an error. I have a set of functions which I want to import in the python Add-In script at the time of execution, but when I built Add-In with "import stats" line then tools are unresponsive. Any suggestions whether it is possible to import functions in the Add-In script?

```
import arcpy
import os
import pythonaddins
import stats

optfolder = "C:/temp"

class AoI(object):
"""Implementation for rectangle_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 5
        self.shape = 'Rectangle'
        os.makedirs(optfolder)

    def onRectangle(self, rectangle_geometry):
   """Occurs when the rectangle is drawn and the mouse button is released.
    The rectangle is a extent object."""

        extent = rectangle_geometry
        arcpy.Clip_management(r'C:/temp/ras', "%f %f %f %f" %(extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax),
                              optfolder + '/ras1', "#", "#", "NONE")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Can you perhaps post your code so that we can see where you are placing the import statement?

Comment: Imports work fine for me. What is the stats module? If it is this, it will not work on Python 2.7: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats/0.1.2a

Comment: No, I am not using that and instead its a custom made library for testing with Add-In. Have you tried importing that from within python Add-In?

Comment: Importing what?

Comment: a bit of confusion: So you simply imported above stats library not with Python 2.7, right?
My question is tied to python Add-In (Python 2.7).

Comment: No I did not. I was only trying to determine whether *you* were trying to import a library built for Python 3.x from Python 2.x. I can import homemade modules without issue.

Comment: Do you understand [how importing works](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/imports.html), i.e. is the module accessible? Are you sure you aren't getting an `ImportError` that is being swallowed by ArcMap?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If an unhandled exception, such as an [`ImportError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError), occurs before the add-in classes are instantiated they will become unresponsive, be given a `[Missing]` label, and have a red symbol for their icon in the case of items on toolbars or in menus.

You can confirm whether an import error is happening by wrapping your import statement with an exception handler and displaying its message in a message box, e.g.:

```
try:
    import stats
except ImportError as e:
    pythonaddins.MessageBox(e.message, "ImportError")
```

[image: Screenshot]

I suspect this is the case here. You need to ensure that your `stats` module is actually discoverable by Python. You will want to read up on how importing works if you are not sure about this:

- [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) - Frederik Lundh's effbot.org site
- [Modules and Imports](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sys/imports.html) - Doug Hellmann's PyMOTW site
- [Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) - The standard Python Tutorial, section 6
- [What are the “best practices” for using import in a module?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) - Python Programming FAQ

**NOTE:** If you are trying to package your `stats` module with your add-in, e.g. by placing it in the `Install` folder alongside your add-in .py file(s), see this [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/60361-Separating-business-logic-and-add-in-script-Python-Add-In), which suggests adding the following line to your add-in .py file before your `stats` import statement:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

You'll need to import the `sys` and `os` modules before that as well.

Comment: Ditto, very helpful succinct info for testing/correction at 10.2.x, thank you for posting.  Files were being copied to the AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.2\AssemblyCache directory -- Wayne

Comment: Your screenshot on this question at http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/5558/f501a77be06e46189576830.png
 seems to no longer be reachable.