# Run Python child script using Python Add-In button class?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-addin

I have a Python script which I want to execute using Python Add-In button class. Right now, I am using following:

```py
class child(object):
    """Implementation for Toolbar_addin.button2 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        os.system('C:/temp/child.py')
```

but it returns nothing when I click Python Add-In button as part of sub-menu. Is it the right way to fire child scripts using button class?

Note: child script works perfectly as a stand alone script

Comment: Why not import the python module and just call methods on it?

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly: I imported modules and generated few outputs using python Add-In. This final step will use outputs from previous steps and do some random calculations. So it has to be fired from a button.

Comment: Just put child.py somewhere you Add-in can see it.  In the same folder should work and just do `import child` and then you can call any of the methods.

Comment: child is in the same folder as Add-In logic script. Importing it gives an error (no such module exists -- since it is not a library). I tried following but no avail:
subprocess.call(['C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.1/python.exe','C:/temp/child.py'])

Comment: You can always import any Python file, Python just needs to see where it is. Try `sys.path.append("C:\\Temp")` then `import child`

Comment: I already have following as part of Add-In script:
`sMyPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)`
`sys.path.insert(0, sMyPath)`

importing child failed with both above and following: `sys.path.append("C:...)`

Comment: then there must be something else going on.  Can you post more of your code, including any errors and child.py

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8841/discussion-between-ibe-and-nathan-w)

Comment: Related: [Import functions in python Add-In logic script](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/49728/753)

Answer (score 3):

@NathanW's suggestion works for me and is what I would suggest doing as well.

I have in the Install folder within my Python Add-in directory:

- `child.py`:

  ```py
  import os, datetime

  def writeDummyFile(path):
      with open(path, "w") as f:
          f.write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime())

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      writeDummyFile(r"C:\temp\test.txt")
      with open(r"C:\temp\test.txt", "r") as f:
          print f.readline()
  ```

  (when run standalone prints the current time as read from the just-written file)
- `TestChildScriptAddin.py`:

  ```py
  import arcpy
  import pythonaddins
  import sys
  import os

  sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  import child

  class LaunchChildScriptButton(object):
      """Implementation for LaunchChildScript.button (Button)"""
      def __init__(self):
          self.enabled = True
          self.checked = False
      def onClick(self):
          child.writeDummyFile(r"C:\temp\test.txt")
  ```

  (when clicked, the current time is written to the file)

This works fine for me at 10.1 SP1. Have you tried doing something similar (barebones test)?

Comment: I have tried similar text writing under button and within child script as well before posting question -- works in both cases. It seems that the problem is occurring due to the declaration of global variables in the child script. I will comment them out to test further.

Comment: Post a complete code sample that reproduces the problem otherwise we are getting nowhere.

Comment: Main error source was: saving raster data with FGDBR or GRID format. So I changed environmental settings and set scratch workspace as an intermediate folder on hard disk, instead of "Default.gdb". It solved the issue. Thanks everyone for answers.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to change

```
os.system('C:/temp/child.py')
```

to

```
os.startfile('C:/temp/child.py')
```

this should run the script.

Answer (score -1):

Both suggestions by **Hotpepper** worked for me. Perhaps you should consider:

`os.system('C:\\temp\\child.py')`

`os.startfile('C:\\temp\\child.py')`

I mean (`\\`) instead to (`/`)