# What does [missing] on ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop Python addin mean?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I need to load all layer names into a combo box. I did the same using esri site. But the tool is showing [missing].

```
import arcpy import pythonaddins 

class LayersComboBoxClass(object):

    """Implementation for Tools_addin.combobox (ComboBox)""" 

    def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True

    def onFocus(self, focused):
        # When the combo box has focus, update the combo box with the list of layer names. if focused:
        self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        # Edit position in code
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd)
        self.items = ["item1",item2]
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please post the code that is giving you trouble? It's difficult to give advice without knowing what doesn't work.

Comment: See this answer for some troubleshooting advice: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49845/753

Comment: I used http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/combo_box/014p00000028000000/  . But it is not working. What change I need to make. I got output as [Missing].

Comment: Going out on a limb, I am guessing you have misnamed something between the config file and the Python file. Either start over clean, or post your whole code project including XML config file somewhere, e.g. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: import arcpy
import pythonaddins
class LayersComboBoxClass(object):"""Implementation for Tools_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
     
def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
def onFocus(self, focused):
  # When the combo box has focus, update the combo box with the list of layer names.
 if focused:
  self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
  layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd)
  self.items = ["item1",item2]      # Please check it and let me know what is the error. Sample combobox

Comment: Please edit your code into your Question rather than the Comment box because the former has much better formatting options.

Comment: @SanthoshSamban change this line self.items  = [fL.name for fL in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd) if not fL.isGroupLayer] # Add all names in list items but ignore groupLayer

Answer (score 0):

In the **ArcGIS 10.2 Online Help** there is a **[Debugging Python add-ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p0000001n000000)** page which says:

> Anytime a tool or button fails to load and displays Missing on the
>   toolbar instead of the expected icon or name, it is commonly due to a
>   Python syntax error. Recheck your Python script for syntax errors or
>   incorrect inputs to Python functions.